# How to avoid overwriting event when productId is different?

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I have a list of products. Each product has an `id` and `description`.

```
<div *ngFor="let product of products">
  <input type="text" [ngModel]="product.description" (ngModelChange)="onEdit($event, product.id)">
</div>
```

---

```
editStream: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

ngOnInit() {
  this.editStream
    .debounceTime(1000)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .mergeMap(x => Observable.of(x))
    .subscribe(x => {
      // based on product id, update its description in the database
    });

}

private onEdit(description: string, id: string) {
  this.editStream.emit({ description, id });
}
```

It works well when I edit one product's description.

However, if I edit `product1`'s description, then edit `product2`'s description immediately (time interval is less than 1s), only `product2`'s description will be updated.

I guess this is because `product2`'s event overwrites `product1`'s event, and I only subscribe at one place.

How can I solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `distinctUntilChanged()` you need a different `Observable` for each `product`.

```
this.products.forEach(p => this.editStreams.push(new EventEmitter())
```

```
<div *ngFor="let product of products let i=index">
  <input type="text" [ngModel]="product.description" (ngModelChange)="onEdit($event, i, product.id)">
</div>
```

```
private onEdit(description: string, id: string) {
  this.editStreams[i].emit({ description, id });
}
```

Comment: Hm, what do you mean "different Observable for each product"?

Comment: Got it, is there a smart way to create certain number (based on product number) of `editStream`? Use an editStream array?

Comment: I updated my answer with a few code snippets. You also would need to subscribe to each item in `editStreams` individually (what you do in `ngOnInit()`). I don't know of a smarter way. That doesn't mean there isn't one ;-)

Comment: Looks great. But say I have 500 products. Your way needs create 500. Maybe create editStream **when only need**. Most time only 1 or 2. Because in 1s, you can only edit 2 together. Can you give me some hint  how to do this?

Comment: You might want to setup just one at the time when the input is focused. `(focus)="setupObservable(i)"`, and when one is already set up, unsubscribe it.